# return view stopped working in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 web application return View() stopped working for some reasons. My controller has a simple index method as below

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

whereas the following is working fine

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the Index method it does get a hit but no call to the index view. I cleaned the solution, restarted VS 2012, tried different browsers but nothing works.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: On my system it works fine and it should

Comment: Exactly, it should work and I don't mind using the view name inside View but curious why it would stop working on my system

Comment: when you say it stopped working, do you mean that it throws an exception? do you have an error? a stack trace?

Comment: No errors at all to give any clues, except I get a blank page.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have another Index.cshtml somewhere in your Views Folder?

Comment: what it renders on page in first case

Comment: Nope. I have even tried creating a new view with the name Index2 and created another action method and the result is the same no call to the view until i specify the view name insdie the return view method

Comment: i mean to say what happens when you only call ``View()``?? what is displayed on page?

Comment: Nothing is displayed on the page. Its completely blank. I can reach other actions by typing in the the URL in the browsers but the index method call as below show nothing http://localhost:62528/dataset/index

Comment: Are you including using System.Web.Http and using System.Web.Mvc in your controller class?

Comment: Yes including both the namespaces

Comment: if you create a noddy template application and try running that, does it work fine?

Comment: Just created new test web app project and yes in the new application it does work fine as expected. Index action calls and renders the index view. I've been working with my existing application for last 1 month or so and It was all working fine and suddenly it stopped working. I installed T4MVC package from NUGET recently in my exisiting APP. To rule out this package causing any trouble, I installed the same package in the test application and that does not trigger the issue. No idea what has happened and how to fix it